# Handling pagination with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a JSON response from the server that is paginated.

```
{
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "ABC12",
            "name": "Networks",
            "description": null,
            "status": "active",
            "teams": [
                {
                    "id": "XYZ12",
                    "type": "team_reference",
                    "summary": "Network Systems ",
                }
            ],
            "acknowledgement_timeout": null,
            "auto_resolve_timeout": null,
            "alert_grouping": "intelligent",
            "alert_grouping_timeout": null,
            "integrations": [],
            "response_play": null,
            "type": "service",
            "summary": "All Events",
        }
     ],
     "limit": 25,
     "offset": 0,
     "total": null,
     "more": true
}
```

`limit - max I can set is 100.`

`offset - If specified, shows results from that point.`

`more - If TRUE, there are more results. If FALSE, that is the end.`

for more info on this pagination - https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/docs/pagination

I need to match the `name` "Networks" and get its corresponding `id` "ABC12". The problem i have to paginate make multiple calls to the API.

I have written this so far.

```
- name: PagerDuty API call - GET Service ID
  uri:
    url: "https://api.pagerduty.com/services?/?limit={{ x }}&offset={{ x+1 }}"
    method: GET
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2"
      Authorization: "Token token={{ api_token }}"
 register: json_resp
```

1. how do I set the value of `x` to `25` and make API calls and append the results to `json_resp` until `more` is false?

OR

2. how do I make multiple API calls until I find the match. If I found a match, then stop making the call.

Or is there a better cleaner way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated, very new to ansible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a curl to the url first to get the headers. And set_fact for your limit/offset, and used [with_sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) in the uri module.
I did it this way, but you should be able to modify it to your needs. 'total_pages' returns like this 'X-Total-Pages: 2' so there may be a more elegant way of getting the total number of pages besides doing a split but this worked for me.

```
---
- name: Get number of pages
  command: |
    curl -I -s {{ api_url }} -H {{ private_token }}
  register: pagination
  failed_when: pagination.rc > 0 or '200 OK' not in pagination.stdout

- set_fact:
    total_pages: "{{ pagination.stdout | regex_search('X-Total-Pages: \\d') }}"

- name: Gather all projects in group
  uri:
    url: "{{ api_url }}"
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ private_token }}"
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body:
      top_level_only: false
      page: "{{ item }}"
  register: group_projects
  with_sequence: start=1 end={{ total_pages.split()[1] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a better cleaner way to do this?

The cleanest way of handling this situation would be to write an Ansible module for interacting with the pagerduty API. Your module would deal with the pagination and then return the complete result set to your playbook.

There is some information about developing Ansible modules [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html).

Ansible already includes a couple of modules that interact with pagerduty; perhaps the [pagerduty](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/monitoring/pagerduty.py) module could serve as as a model.

Comment: Hi @larsks. Thanks for your response, i'm implementing a very small solution. Writing a module is not allowed, unfortunately. Is there a way to do this in ansible play itself?

Comment: Writing a module is...not allowed? Is this homework? Writing a module is really going to be the cleanest and most effective way of solving this particular issue. You could of course also write a Python or shell script and run that with the [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) module.